# Unexpected Numpy / Py3k coercion rules

Tags: python, numpy, typing, coerce

I was looking for a bug in a program, and I discovered that it was produced by an unexpected behavior from Numpy...

When doing, e.g., a simple arithmetic operation on different integer types using Python3k and Numpy, like

(numpy.uint64) + (int)

the result is... a numpy.float64

Here's an example:

```
v = numpy.array([10**16+1], dtype=numpy.uint64)
print(v[0])
v[0] += 1
print(v[0])
```

It produce the following result :

```
10000000000000001
10000000000000000
```

Which can be quite unexpected when you're dealing with integers to avoid rounding errors...

The above "problem" can easily be solved by replacing 1 by numpy.uint64(1), but I can see many bugs coming from this. What are the rules and logic behind this situation? Is there any documentation about the way coercions are done in such a case? I couldn't find it.

I thought before that you could have some insight on the coercions by using .item() but it's even more misleading :

```
v = numpy.array([10**16+1], dtype=numpy.uint64)
print(type(v[0].item()))
v[0] = v[0].item() + 1
print(v[0])
```

produces

```
<class 'int'>
10000000000000001
10000000000000002
```

So .item() transforms the numpy.uint64 into int, and if you explicitely use it in the arithmetic operation, it works.

I'm surprised (but I lack numpy experience, I guess), that, when 'a' corresponds to a numpy specific dtype,

```
a.item() + 1
```

and

```
a + 1
```

don't produce the same results... and thus gives different results when converted back to a numpy dtype.

(The environment used is an up-to-date Pyzo distribution, via IEP, if it matters. I usually use Python 2, but I had to do a couple test in Py3k, and it was a convenient way to do it.)

Comment: It works fine with `dtype=np.int64` instead of `dtype=np.uint64` (both for python 2 and 3, numpy 1.6 and 1.9). I really don't understand why that would be happening, sounds like a bug... Just use `np.int64`, there is no reason to use `uint64`, overflowing at `2⁶⁴ - 1` or `2⁶³ - 1`  is pretty much the same thing for all practical purposes.

Comment: That's interesting... Indeed, that works with `dtype=np.int64`... Not sure if it's a bug (although it seems like a bug to me), since both `np.int32 + int` and `np.uint32 + int` both get converted to `np.int64`, probably to avoid overflow. Why `np.int64 + int` becomes `np.int64` and `np.uint64 + int` becomes `np.float64` still eludes me. I've plently of workarounds, but I'd like to know if there's a reason behind this, and where I can find it. Thanks for the comment...

Comment: Here is the corresponding [numpy issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5745), that makes sens at some level although it is still not very intuitive.

Comment: No, but it's enough for me to find at least a reference on this matter... That answer my question. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

It works fine with:

```
dtype=np.int64
```

instead of:

```
dtype=np.uint64
```

both for python 2 and 3, numpy 1.6 and 1.9.

Just use:

```
np.int64
```

there is no reason to use `uint64`, overflowing at `2⁶⁴ - 1` or `2⁶³ - 1` is pretty much the same thing for all practical purposes.

**References**

- [numpy Issue #5745: uint64 converted silently to float64 when adding an int](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5745)

Comment: I strongly disagree that it's the same thing for all practical purposes...

I often need exact integer types when dealing with binary data. The question is old, but I think I needed it at the time (I've definitively used it before and after). With int64, you'll have comparison issues, and warning for overflow.

That being said, it's just an unexpected implicit conversion choice, and it's easy to circumvent, so it's not really an issue, but I think it should be more obvious in the numpy documentation. Not that there's not plently of cases where numpy documentation is far from perfect :/